# p-dropdown doesn't setValue manually with Reactive Form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I'm trying to set manually the form after some services retrieve some information, and I need to set back again to the dropdown the values (using setTimeout for practicity).

Along side are a normal selector which work accordingly to what I expected. I did the same with the p-dropdown i doesn't work at all.

It detected the change by the method onChange but again nothing happen.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ge9bjb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fdropdown-reactive-forms-demo.ts

Maybe it need some reference on the `<p-dropdown>` in order to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a work around to solve this issue:

1. Add a template reference on the `<p-dropdown>` like `#dd`:

```
    <p-dropdown
      #dd
      formControlName="city"
      [options]="cities"
      optionLabel="name"
      (onChange)="onChange($event)"
    ></p-dropdown>
```

2. Use `@ViewChild` to read the template refenece:

```
  @ViewChild('dd') dd:Dropdown
```

3. Add the following in `SetTimeout` to update the model value:

```
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.cityName?.patchValue(this.cities[1], { onlySelf: true });
      this.dd.updateModel(this.cities[1]) // add this line to update model
      console.log(this.formGroup.getRawValue().city);
      console.log(this.formGroup2.getRawValue().cityName);
    }, 2000);
```

That should works fine with you.

> I think that happened because of `modelValue` signal in dropdown
> component under the hood.

Comment: It worked thanks, also upgrading "primeng": "16.7.0" to "primeng": "16.7.1" in package.json fix this bug